# What type of knot do wayfinders tie in Moana?

Tags: props, moana

In *Moana*, Maui the demigod and later a few [Motunui](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Motunui) sailor are shown tying this knot.

[image: Wayfinders tie knots in Moana]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/sailing/comments/5il4ac/swinging_rope_knot_in_moana_movie/

Comment: Why has this question suddenly become off-topic after being left alone for almost 3 years?

Comment: It got a new answer yesterday, and thus got some attention.

Comment: @GamerGypps Trivia questions that do not appreciably add to the understanding of the movie are off-topic. If there were a scene or a plot point about tying knots (perhaps somebody doing it wrong, and that failure causing a problem) it could be on topic. If it's presented as normal boating people doing normal boating things, then it's trivia here - it's not about the movie, it's about boating.

Comment: Definitely firm on this being off-topic. If this kind of question is permissible then you could also ask what material their clothes are made of, the style of their hair, what type of wood the boats are made from, etc. Though these elements **are** in the film they're still not exactly germane to the film itself (plot, character development, production, animation tools and techniques, etc.).

Comment: @Charles Being mass-producible doesn't necessarily make a class of questions off-topic. For example, [tag:plot-explanation] is on-topic even though you could also ask about every single minor plot detail and get a hundred low-quality questions out of a single film.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm saying that the type of knot they make is essentially a trivial feature of the film, just like all the other stuff I mentioned would be too. Had nothing to do with being "mass-producible" or not, as you put it.

Comment: @Charles "*If this kind of question is permissible then you could also ask ...*" sounded like an argument about it being mass producible.

Answer (score 21):

This knot is called [***Bowline Knot***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline#Tying).

[image]

> Bowline is an ancient and simple knot used to form a fixed loop at the end of a rope. It has the virtues of being both easy to tie and untie; most notably, it is easy to untie after being subjected to a load.
>
> **The bowline is commonly used in sailing small craft, for example to fasten a halyard to the head of a sail or to tie a jib sheet to a clew of a jib.**

Comment: As someone who knows how to tie this knot (it's actually fairly simple), looking at the image in the question, it looks like that is what they are beginning to tie.

Comment: The bowline makes actually quite a lot of sense in this context, because it's one of the first knots a newbie sailor usually has to learn and for most people it is a considerable difficulty leap from those you learn before (figure-eight, reef-knot, clove hitch).

Answer (score -4):

The knot they tie in Moana is often mistaken as a bowline, BUT it is actually called a Flying Bowline, also known as a Speed Bowline or a Tugboat Bowline.

It's a common knot used by sailors to throw a loop in the end of a rope. They do this to throw a loop to someone who has gone overboard or to throw a loop over a cleat or boring of a kind when tying something off.

Comment: You appear to be the owner of that blog at the end. You should read [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: there's already another answer with this information, please do not repeat what's already posted.